# Is it compulsory to put masters and slaves config file to all slaves and secondary name node?

Tags: hadoop

When we are installing hadoop in multi cluster mode, do we need to give an entry of masters and slaves details to all slaves and secondary name node?

Comment: This file is not a mandatory file. This is only required if you are starting/stopping the cluster using start-all.sh and stop-all.sh script. If you want to use this, then no need to keep in all the machines. Keep it in a machine where you trigger the start-all.sh or stop-all.sh script.

Comment: Thanks Amal G Jose... Next time i will come up with new questions. Because I am start learning this technology so need all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

While installing Hadoop in multinode cluster, it is not mandatory to keep slaves and masters files in Slave(DN+TT/NN) machines and Secondary NameNode machine.

In Hadoop project, these two files contain the IP addresses of slaves and secondary namenode machine. These two files required only at time of starting and stoping the cluster.

We usually start or stop the cluster from Master machine (NN+JT/RM). So keep these two files in Master machine and keeping them in slaves and secondary namenode machine is optional.

Comment: Thanks @user1145303... Next time i will come up with new questions. Because I am start learning this technology so need all of your help.